# removing folder access restrictions from an external drive

Tags: windows-vista, permissions

While playing around with the folder and file permissions, now I cannot access some of my files and folders in Windows Vista.  How could I remove all kinds of access restrictions, so that I can use this drive from any other computer without problems? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this [How to take ownership of a file or folder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659.aspx) at the drive level and then make the permission changes I need and force a propagation to sub-folders and files. Then I would move the stuff off of it, kill the partition and recreate it so it has default permissions and such. If you want to use it on other machines it might be best to format it as FAT32 NTFS can be picky about permissions sometimes when connecting from one machine to another.